# Eliding copy/move when taking members out of a temporary

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I'd like to take out members of a temporary without unnecessary moving or copying.

Suppose I have:

```
class TP {
    T _t1, _t2;
};
```

I'd like to get `_t1`, and `_t2` from `TP()`. Is it possible without copying/moving members?

I've tried with tuples and trying to "forward" (I don't think it's possible) the members, but the best I could get was a move, or members dying immediately.

In the following playground using `B::as_tuple2` ends up with members dying too soon, unless the result is bound to a non-ref type, then members are moved. `B::as_tuple` simply moves is safe with `auto` on client side.

I suppose this should be technically possible, since the temporary dies immediately, and the member do die while they could bound to variables on the calling site (Am I wrong?), and structured binding of a similar struct works as intended.

Is it possible to extend/pass life of the member onto an outside variable, or elide the move/copy? I need it with c++14 version, but I couldn't get it to work on c++17 either, so I am interested in both.

[Playground](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd8055fa78a4167f):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
class Shawty {
/**
 * Pronounced shouty.
 **/
    public:
    Shawty() : _id(Shawty::id++) {cout << _id << " ctor\n"; }
    Shawty(Shawty && s) : _id(Shawty::id++) { cout << _id << " moved from " << s._id << "\n"; }
    Shawty(const Shawty & s) : _id(Shawty::id++) { cout << _id << " copied from " << s._id << "\n"; }
    Shawty& operator=(Shawty && s) { cout << _id << " =moved from " << s._id << "\n"; return *this;}
    Shawty& operator=(Shawty & s) { cout << _id << " =copied from " << s._id << "\n"; return *this;}
    ~Shawty() {cout << _id << " dtor\n"; }
    int _id;
    static int id;
};
int Shawty::id = 0;

class B {
public:
    auto as_tuple() && {return std::make_tuple(std::move(_s1), std::move(_s2));}
    auto as_tuple2() && {return std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(_s1), std::move(_s2));}

private:
    Shawty _s1, _s2;
};

struct S {
    Shawty _s1, _s2;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "----------\n";
    auto [s1, s2] = B().as_tuple2();
    std::cout << "---------\n";
    auto tpl1 = B().as_tuple2();
    std::cout << "----------\n";
    std::tuple<Shawty, Shawty> tpl2 = B().as_tuple2();
    std::cout << "----------\n";

    std::cout << std::get<0>(tpl1)._id << '\n';
    std::cout << std::get<1>(tpl1)._id << '\n';
    std::cout << std::get<0>(tpl2)._id << '\n';
    std::cout << std::get<1>(tpl2)._id << '\n';
    std::cout << s1._id << '\n';
    std::cout << s2._id << '\n';

    std::cout << "--struct--\n";
    auto [s3, s4] = S{};
    std::cout << s3._id << '\n';
    std::cout << s4._id << '\n';
    std::cout << "----------\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suppose `class TP {
    T t1, t2, t3;
};` where you only want `t1`, `t3`, how would you handle that (layout of structure) ?

Comment: The example with structured binding is used to show that something similar is possible. I image writing this as a tuple of references, so I could do return `return tuple<T&&, T&&>{std::move(t1), std::move(t3)};` and let `t2` die. I'd consider allowing such things for all members and leaving object in unspecified stated. But the case with temporary seems simpler, because it seems that the original members could simply bind to new variables and extend their life time, like in copy elision. Do you suggest it might be technically challenging or performance crippling, due to memory layout?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to extend the lifetime of more than one member beyond the lifetime of the super object.

So, the only way to "get" members without copying is to keep the super object alive, and refer to them:

```
// member function
auto as_tuple3() & {
    return std::make_tuple(std::ref(_s1), std::ref(_s2));
}

// usage
B b;
auto [s1, s2] = b.as_tuple3();
```

---

An example of extending lifetime of the object by binding a reference to a single member. Note that this requires the member to be accessible from where the reference is bound (not the case in your example, where the member is private):

```
auto&& s1 = B{}._s1;
```

Comment: It is possible to extend the lifetime of **one** member though.

Comment: @Jarod42 I did not know that. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: I would say http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf § 15.2 page 284

Comment: @xhamr that particular rule seems to have been added to the C++20 draft, but appears to be mainly for clarification/better wording. The rule `the temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference` is in C++17.

Comment: Why not `std::tie( _s1, _s2 )`?  Seems shorter and less error prone.  Also note that you could augment `TP` to support structured binding and use that to create aliases.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont `std::tie` wouldn't let you deduce their type though, would it?

Comment: @user2079303 Why not?  Literally replace the return expression with that.  You get the same type, 3 times fewer characters, and less repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Add support for structured binding to your `B` type.

```
class B {
public:
    template<std::size_t I, class Self,
        std::enable_if_t< std::is_same_v<B, std::decay_t<Self>>, bool> = true
    >
    friend constexpr decltype(auto) get(Self&& self) {
        if constexpr(I==0)
        {
            using R = decltype(std::forward<Self>(self)._s1)&&;
            return (R)std::forward<Self>(self)._s1;
        }
        else if constexpr(I==1)
        {
            using R = decltype(std::forward<Self>(self)._s2)&&;
            return (R)std::forward<Self>(self)._s2;
        }
    }
private:
    Shawty _s1, _s2;
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    struct tuple_size<::B>:std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2> {};
    template<std::size_t N>
    struct tuple_element<N, ::B>{using type=Shawty;};
}
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "----------\n";
    {
        auto&& [s1, s2] = B();
    }
}
```

output:

> ```
>  ----------
>  0 ctor
>  1 ctor
>  1 dtor
>  0 dtor
> ```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/400cc774ff53f70a).

This is the best I can do.  Note that `s1` and `s2` are references into a lifetime-extended version of `B`.

Comment: For the record, this solution is implementing interface for structure binding. Case 2 as described on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @luk32 Yes; I had added a preamble to say that probably since you refreshed the page.